# how much unreal engine take time and total disk space to install in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unreal-engine4

How much unreal engine take my disk space and time to completely install in Ubuntu 20.04 ?
I also tried one time to install it according Unreal Documentation but it take  my whole night even then it was not installed . After that , I Quit . If anyone have idea , about this then please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time for building Unreal Engine depends on the hardware of your computer.But generally it will take around 1 hour to finish the build with a computer having a  good hardware. As per the documentation unreal engine recommends 100GB of disk space.